# Adding Executables, Dependencies and Target Link Libraries - Client Example

Tags: ros, actionlib-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 and in the tutorial [http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionClient], under section 1.3, CMakeLists.txt is modified to add Executables, Dependencies and Target Link Libraries.  Since this builds on the work of the SimpleActionServer, should these be ADDED to this file or should they replace what was used for the prior lesson:

http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29

```
add_executable(fibonacci_server src/fibonacci_server.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
  fibonacci_server
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_dependencies(
  fibonacci_server
  ${learning_actionlib_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
)
```

I can get the tutorial for the client working fine when I replace the above dependencies, link libraries and executables. But, the directions seem to say ADD the new dependencies, link libraries and executables to what was used for the client example.  If that is the case, how do you add multiple dependencies, executables and link libraries.  I haven't found the correct syntax.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220191/adding-executables,-dependencies-and-target-link-libraries---client-example/) by [d7x](https://answers.ros.org/users/23168/d7x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes; you should be adding to the CMakeLists from the previous tutorial.

You shouldn't be trying to combine multiple statements from the different tutorials.

For example, each call to `add_executable()` in cmake defines a new executable that you're trying to compile, and you want to compile each tutorial, so you should have two separate calls to `add_executable()`

Your final CMakeLists should look something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(learning_actionlib)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp actionlib actionlib_msgs)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

add_action_files(
  DIRECTORY action
  FILES Fibonacci.action
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES actionlib_msgs std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS actionlib_msgs
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(fibonacci_server src/fibonacci_server.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
  fibonacci_server
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_dependencies(
  fibonacci_server
  ${learning_actionlib_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
)

add_executable(fibonacci_client src/fibonacci_client.cpp)

target_link_libraries( 
  fibonacci_client
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_dependencies(
  fibonacci_client
  ${learning_actionlib_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
)
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [d7x](https://answers.ros.org/users/23168/d7x/) on 2015-10-30**:
Perfect, thanks for explaining this.